# Check which side has more space around mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, tooltip, mouseevent

I am building a custom tooltip functionality where I am supposed to show a video as a tooltipo over an image. Now, I have some initial thing working, but I am stuck at finding the area around mouse pointer where I should display the tooltip.

I am having the tooltip always visible at the bottom right of mouse cursor, no matter where mouse currently is in screen, this is what I have so far :

```
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var x = e.clientX, y = e.clientY;
    tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 10) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 10) + 'px';
};
```

where tooltip is my target element.
What I am looking for, is, that my code should find the largest area around mouse available on screen, and adjust the tooltip to display there. Any pointers for this would help a lot.

Note: jQuery is not an option, I have to build in core JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can get the width and the **dimensions of the viewport** using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` (in my example below `this` refers to `window` because the code is running inside `window`)
2. Using viewport dimensions and the mouse position using `ev.clientX/Y` you can **determine the pixel space** on the left/right and top/bottom side of the cursor as in example below.
3. Using property `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` we get the **dimensions of the tooltip** and we can use that to set the **tooltip position relative to cursor position**. For example if the topLeft quadrant is the largest, the tooltip will show top left relatively to cursor (meaning the bottom right corner of the tooltip will "touch" the cursor).

I hope this example helps :).

```js
 var tooltip = this.document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip")[0];
window.onmousemove = function(ev) {
  // Getting pixel space 
  var leftPixelSpace = ev.clientX;
  var rightPixelSpace = this.innerWidth - leftPixelSpace; 
  var topPixelSpace = ev.clientY;
  var bottomPixelSpace = this.innerHeight - topPixelSpace;

  // Determining the position of topleft corner of the tooltip
  var tooltipPosX = leftPixelSpace > rightPixelSpace ? leftPixelSpace  - tooltip.offsetWidth : leftPixelSpace;
  var tooltipPosY = topPixelSpace > bottomPixelSpace ? topPixelSpace - tooltip.offsetHeight : topPixelSpace;
  
  // Setting tooltip position 
  tooltip.style.left = tooltipPosX+"px";
  tooltip.style.top = tooltipPosY+"px";
};
```

```css
.tooltip {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color : lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">floating tooltip</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? A `switch` with conditions for calculating in which quadrant the mouse cursor is.

```js
var wM = window.innerWidth / 2;
var hM = window.innerHeight / 2;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var w = e.clientX;
    var h = e.clientY;
    var pos;
    switch (true) {
        case (w <= wM && h <= hM):
            pos = 'top-left';
            break;
        case (w <= wM && h >= hM):
            pos = 'bottom-left';
            break;
        case (w > wM && h < hM):
            pos = 'top-right';
            break;
        case (w > wM && h > hM):
            pos = 'bottom-right';
            break;
 default:
            pos = undefined;//Here you could even assign a default quadrant to relay on, in case any condition is met.
    }
    console.log(pos);
});
```

- `wM` for widthMiddle, the middle point in the window's width.
- `hM`: same, but with the height.
- `w` for the mouse width/X position; `h` for height/Y.
- A switch based on conditions according to a quadrant system.